# Too-short a return for baseboard

Tags: trim, carpentry, baseboard, finishing, trim-carpentry

How would you deal with this situation as far as installing baseboard? Would you do a return?

[image]

Comment: Can the grey box be moved out a bit, to make it even with the wall?  Is there a door on that box?   Can either end the baseboard at the corner or add a filler piece to the box and run the baseboard across it.

Comment: The grey is a built-in shelf without a door.

Comment: Without knowing what the rest of the base looks like, a return is pretty much the only choice. If that segment of wall is 5", I'd make the chunk of base 4-7/8".

Comment: Would you just glue the return in? It's less than 1/2" and probably couldn't take a nail.

Comment: Is the gap below the bottom shelf a concern at all?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 way to do this. Some are more detailed and take a bit more skill than others.

You can just cut the left end of the baseboard at an an angle and paint.  It is somewhat low end.

You can flat miter cut the baseboard like a picture frame.  It may suit you , or not.

The last thing is to cut an external angle on the left side and cut a right external angle out of another piece of base. Then cut that piece the thickness of the baseboard and glue it on. The base then returns on itself.

Here is an excellent [video of 3 returns for baseboards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QtxwcD7yP8). It shows how to do all 3.

You can decide what works best for you.

Comment: Now the link is added to better explain the 3 choices.

Comment: I couldn't find a good video to describe it, but using tape to "clamp" the return works well with slow setting (ie, pva) glues.

Comment: The problem here is that there's a short piece of outside corner.  I suppose the "self return" variation could be cut with a little extra length on the little piece, to wrap around the corner.